# I am continuously getting Audit Failure on the computer. Does that mean someone is trying to brute force to the computer?

Tags: windows, brute-force-attacks, eventviewer, windows-server-2022

I am getting lots of Audit Failure errors on Windows Logs/Security in event viewer.
See the image below.
Does that mean someone is trying to brute-force to my computer?

[image]

Comment: It could mean anything. Why don't you read the event log entries and see what it's actually about? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4625

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Event ID 4624** is associated with logon events. Multiple instances of this entry is due to Event Viewer recording every logon event (whether from the local user account or system services such as Windows Security) with the same event ID which is 4624

To identify the source of login, **right-click on the event record** and select Properties.

[image: Right Click to Event Record]

In the **General tab**, scroll down and locate the **Logon Information Section**. Here, the Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that occurred. For example, Logon **Type 5 indicates a service-based login**, while **Logon Type 2 indicates user-based login**.

[image: Log Example]

**More Information** - [4625(F): An account failed to log on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4625)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case, the logon type is 3 (Network).